# Instance Creation ( JS )

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I've been reading Substack modules and notice his style of creating a new instace of an Object.

`if (!(this instanceof Browserify)) return new Browserify(files, opts);`
https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/master/index.js#L37

I know `this` in "this" particular case refers to window obj, and that Browserify wont be an instance of this (window).

My question is : What are your thoughts about this way or style for creating an object ? / is this a convenient way of instantiating an object without having to do. 

`var brows = require('browserify')`
and then 
`var x = new brows()`

Comment: i've used  `if(this.Date)return new ...` ; ok, as long as the instance doesn't define ".Date"

Answer (score 4):

Effectively this prevents you from calling the constructor without returning an instance of the object, or simply eliminates the need to use the `new` keyword.  The following do the same thing:

```
var brs = new Browserify();
var brs = Browserify();
```

`brs` will be an instantiated `Browserify` object either way.

As for why this is good or necessary -- I think this is a matter of opinion more than anything else.

Comment: Do you know the technical term for this sort of style ? or where can i find some more information about it. ?